# Java Desktop Capture

Tags: java, ffmpeg, screenshot

I want to continuously capture the entire desktop inside of a java application. As I'm capturing, I'd like to chunk the stream of data into small video files (mp4, WebM) for storage. From my research, it would seem that the [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) Java class and the FFmpeg tool are my best options. However, Robot seems to best-fit the use case of obtaining images, not videos. FFmpeg seems like it may support this, but I've struggled to find definitive documentation. I'm looking to emulate what can be done through Chrome's getUserMedia and desktopCapture APIs along with the [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) JavaScript library. Does anyone have a suggestion for a similar and elegant solution in Java?

Comment: I've seen some ones that convert to gifs, and gifs can convert to mp4's...